# how do you build a newdata data frame based on custom ranges in R

Tags: r, prediction

I have a data frame that includes data from 08:00AM to 12:00PM for Monday through Friday.

I would like to build a linear model and use prediction to predict this data for 12 months.

my data frame is called www:

Result of `dput(head(www,30))`:

```
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(1367409600, 1367413200, 1367416800, 
    1367420400, 1367424000, 1367499600, 1367510400, 1367506800, 1367593200, 
    1367596800, 1367503200, 1367582400, 1367586000, 1367589600, 1367841600, 
    1367942400, 1367931600, 1367935200, 1367938800, 1368028800, 1368018000, 
    1368021600, 1368025200, 1368104400, 1368108000, 1368111600, 1368115200, 
    1368201600, 1368198000, 1368194400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = ""), VOLUME = c(17447212L, 22345495L, 24855225L, 24756301L, 
    23329007L, 20119332L, 21344801L, 22538957L, 24095519L, 22228820L, 
    21975461L, 18383839L, 23157799L, 23964513L, 18507639L, 19638062L, 
    18746896L, 19970344L, 21345079L, 18668067L, 17835332L, 19394764L, 
    20241583L, 18126951L, 19491766L, 19819131L, 18640871L, 20771137L, 
    22540995L, 22409945L)), .Names = c("DATE", "VOLUME"), row.names = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 
    20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
    37L, 38L), class = "data.frame")
```

I can bulild the model as this:

```
lin <- lm(VOLUME~DATE, data=www)
```

and

I could have created the newdata called years by incrementing the latest date and time on my data frame (www) as below:

```
years <- seq(as.Date(c("2013-08-12")),as.Date(c("2014-08-12")), 1)
predictions <- predict(lin, newdata=data.frame(DATE=years), eval=0.95, interval="prediction")
```

Since I am only looking at from 08:12 for business day, How could build my newdata data frame any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a sequence of dates until December 31, 2013 by the hour between 08:00 and 12:00.

```
date <- as.POSIXlt(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXlt("2013-08-12 08:00"), as.POSIXlt("2013-12-31 12:00"), by = "hour"))
hour <- date$hour
newdata <- data.frame(date = date, hour = hour)
newdata <- newdata[newdata$hour >= 8 & newdata$hour <= 12, ]
```

Comment: I am sorry no. I need to build a newdata data frame for the next 3 monts or so which will begin at the end of my data frame time and increment for for one hour (if the hour is between 8 and 12) then go the next day and increment from 8 to 12 do this for 3 months.

Comment: So I edited in how you can create a sequence of dates by the hour, I can't include your predicted values because I don't know which package `lin` is from. And adding it to your dataframe just requires `rbind`